# *Beginner* C++ basic calculator

Tags: c++, calculator

I'm relatively new to programming, but am really enjoying it.  I have taken a couple of classes but mostly code for fun (for now).  I decided to make a program implementing some basic functions, switch statements, and user input.  Please leave any feedback on how to make this program better.  Thanks!

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int add (int x, int y){
return x+y;
};

int divide (int x, int y){
return x/y;
}

int multiply (int x, int y){
return x*y;
}

int subtract (int x, int y){
return x-y;
}


int main(){

int n1;
int n2;
int user14 = 0;

SomeLine:
cout << "Enter your 2 numbers: "<< endl;
cin >> n1;
cin >> n2;


cout << "Ok, now what do you want to do with those numbers? "<< endl;

cout << "1) Add: " << endl;
cout << "2) Divide: "<<endl;
cout << "3) Multiply: "<< endl;
cout << "4) Subtration: "<< endl;

cin >> user14;

switch (user14)
{
    case 1:
    cout << n1+n2 << endl;
        break;
    case 2:
    cout << n1/n2 << endl;
        break;
    case 3:
    cout << n1*n2<< endl;
        break;
    case 4:
    cout << n1-n2 << endl;
        break;

}

char userchoice;
cout << "Would you like to perform any other operations? y/n "<< endl;

cin >> userchoice;

if (userchoice=='y'){
    goto SomeLine;
}
else if(userchoice=='n'){
    goto Exit;
}

Exit:
return 0;

};
```

Comment: This probably belongs on Codereview.

Comment: You're probably right.  This is my first time posting on stack overflow.  Not really sure what's right to post/not post.

Comment: Try and read [What topics can i ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Why do you define functions for add and subtract etc.  And then in the switch statement you don't use them.  I agree you don't need them but then why are they in there?

Comment: I actually wrote this program based around those functions.  I understand that they're not necessary, but I was just trying to understand how to use them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer, because I'm new and there's a few things I can help you out with. I'm not sure if it's encouraged or not to answer on these kinds of posts, but I figured I'd want to help anyways...

The first thing that I noticed is that you made a large amount of functions for all the operations, but never used them, opting for the switch statements instead.

A couple of ways you could have utilized functions in your code:

```
//use in the switch statement
switch(input) {
case 1:
  cout << add(a,b) << endl;
  break;
case 2:
  cout << divide(a,b) << endl;
  break;
```

I chose to include divide in that snippet, because I wanted to tell you about truncating. In C++ and many other programming languages that support types, you'll encounter truncating when converting from a type double to type int.

This occurs in division. If you were dividing 5 by 2 (5/2), you would get 2.5. But, because you're assigning that to an int, it's only stored as 2 (the decimal gets chopped off), because ints aren't capable of dealing with decimals.

For a calculator, I would wholly recommend converting all the int's that you're using to doubles for the truncating error. In the case that you want to do larger calculations for whatever reason more than **2147483647**, then you'd want to use double's as they can store about 15 digits [read more here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_data_types.htm).

Also, don't put semicolons after function brackets (it's only on your add function).

Otherwise, it looks pretty good format-wise, and you're using some cool concepts that I don't use much (goto and switch statements).

Keep it up!

Comment: Thank you so much for the response Carson. I didn’t realize that about truncating. Very helpful. I’ve moved my question over to Code review which seems like a more fitting site for this kind of post. Thanks again!